# max() with struct() in Spark Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have something like the below in spark of which I'm grouping and then trying to find the one with the highest value from my struct.

```
test.map(x => tester(x._1, x._2, x._3, x._4, x._5))
  .toDS
  .select($"ac", $"sk", struct($"num1", struct($"time", $"num1")).as("grp"))
  .groupBy($"ac", $"sk")
  .agg(max($"grp")).show(false)
```

I am not sure how the max function figures out how to decide the max. The reason I used a nested struct is because it seemed to make the max function using num1 instead of the next numbers when everything was in the same struct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `StructTypes` are compared lexicographically - field by field, from left to right and  all fields have to recursively orderable. So in your case:

1. It will compare the first element of the struct.

   - If the elements are not equal it will return the struct with higher value.
   - Otherwise it will proceed to the point 2.
2. Since the second field is complex as well, it will repeat procedure from point 1 this time comparing `time` fields first.

Note that nested `num1` can be evaluated on if top level `num1` fields are equal, therefore it doesn't affect the ordering in practice.

Comment: So basically as long as it can get an evaluation on the first field it will use this for the ordering? From your answer it seems like there is no point to the nested struct as it can evaluate off the un nested num1 without continuing?

Comment: If you care only about `num1` ordering then the nested `struct` is indeed unnecessary `struct($"num1", $"time")` would do just fine.