# SparkSQL - Filter / Reduce an Array of Structs by Key and Logic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Ive been looking at how, in pure SparkSQL (only), ideally using the existing sparkSQL ARRAY functions and lambda logic, to reduce this array of sales lines time based changes (sup dups by `LineId`), down to only the 'latest' (`MAX(Occurred)) by key (LineId)` - i.e giving current state per line.

I was really hoping for a neat *functional* style solution using combinations of specific ARRAY functions (SLICE, FILTER, REDUCE etc - maybe a SQL UDF is needed?), rather then `classic` SQL of unnesting, `ROW_NUMBER OVER` ..., Filter `where rowNum = 1`, re-aggregate remaining back to array type of logic.

The result of this should be the second array, reducing the initial array of 5 rows down to deduped and latest 3 rows.

Many thanks

```json
[
  {
    "OrdNum": "SalesOrderHeader_H1",
    "LineId": "SalesOrderLine_L2",
    "Occurred": "2021-12-01T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "Prod": "P2",
    "Amt": 34,
    "Qty": 2
  },
  {
    "OrdNum": "SalesOrderHeader_H1",
    "LineId": "SalesOrderLine_L1",
    "Occurred": "2021-12-01T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "Prod": "P1",
    "Amt": 13,
    "Qty": 2
  },
  {
    "OrdNum": "SalesOrderHeader_H1",
    "LineId": "SalesOrderLine_L2",
    "Occurred": "2021-12-02T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "Prod": "P2",
    "Amt": 17,
    "Qty": 1
  },
  {
    "OrdNum": "SalesOrderHeader_H1",
    "LineId": "SalesOrderLine_L3",
    "Occurred": "2021-12-02T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "Prod": "P3",
    "Amt": 100,
    "Qty": 5
  },
  {
    "OrdNum": "SalesOrderHeader_H1",
    "LineId": "SalesOrderLine_L3",
    "Occurred": "2021-12-03T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "Prod": "P3",
    "Amt": 60,
    "Qty": 3
  }
]
```

Result should be only the 3 unique lines remaining (1 row for `SalesOrderLine_L1`, `SalesOrderLine_L2`, `SalesOrderLine_L3`), where each is the 'latest' / most recent row `MAX(Occurred)`.  L2 & L3 both have an extra row each that get filtered out.

```json
[
  {
    "OrdNum": "SalesOrderHeader_H1",
    "LineId": "SalesOrderLine_L1",
    "Occurred": "2021-12-01T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "Prod": "P1",
    "Amt": 13,
    "Qty": 2
  },
  {
    "OrdNum": "SalesOrderHeader_H1",
    "LineId": "SalesOrderLine_L2",
    "Occurred": "2021-12-02T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "Prod": "P2",
    "Amt": 17,
    "Qty": 1
  },
  {
    "OrdNum": "SalesOrderHeader_H1",
    "LineId": "SalesOrderLine_L3",
    "Occurred": "2021-12-03T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "Prod": "P3",
    "Amt": 60,
    "Qty": 3
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way by first selecting distinct `LineId` from the original array then transforming the result where for each `LineId` we search for the max element in the `sales` array by using `array_max`. But for this, we need to change the order of attributes in the structs and make `Occurred` as the first attribute (see [how spark compares StructType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52668207/max-with-struct-in-spark-dataset)):

```py
spark.sql("""
    select transform(
            array_distinct(transform(sales, x -> x.LineId)),
            x -> array_max(
                    filter(
                        transform(sales, s -> struct(s.Occurred as Occurred, s.OrdNum as OrdNum, s.LineId as LineId, s.Prod as Prod, s.Amt as Amt, s.Qty as Qty)), 
                        y -> y.LineId = x 
                    )
                )
            ) as sales
    from  sales_table
""").show(truncate=False)

#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|sales                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |
#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#|[[2021-12-02T00:00:00.000+0000, SalesOrderHeader_H1, SalesOrderLine_L2, P2, 17, 1], [2021-12-01T00:00:00.000+0000, SalesOrderHeader_H1, SalesOrderLine_L1, P1, 13, 2], [2021-12-03T00:00:00.000+0000, SalesOrderHeader_H1, SalesOrderLine_L3, P3, 60, 3]]|
#+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

Another way which is similar to the first one but we don't need to change attributes order:

```sql
select transform(
            array_distinct(transform(sales, x -> x.LineId)),
            x -> filter(sales, 
                        y -> y.LineId = x 
                             and y.Occurred = array_max(transform(filter(sales, s -> s.LineId = x), t -> t.Occurred))
                        )[0]
            ) as sales
from  sales_table
```

Comment: Wow cool will grab a coffee, digest and test it out!  Ive done some function composition like this to date, this is defo very cool thanks.  Question:  generally speaking such a class of transformation (on bounded arrays) is going to be very performant right given its working on an array where data colocated and 'prejoined' (compared against separate delta tables for header and line) - well it is what I've always assumed and given alot of data is shaped like this always try to use array functions first.  Would love to see Spark add more Array functions added over time.  Anyways - thanks heaps!

Comment: Despite the coolness of above - what we need is Spark to add:  FILTER(Expr,GroupingKey,Func)